# Pandas concatenate function problem

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of shape `(1388, 14)` where two of the columns represent the  years of education of each parent. Both these columns have missing values, which are denoted as `'.'` in the original dataset. What I need to do is clear the dataframe from these entries and then concatenate the variables of interest into a new dataframe so I can run a regression. So far I have this:

```
df_bwght = pd.read_excel('bwght.xls')
df_bwght.drop(df_bwght[df_bwght.motheduc=='.'].index, inplace=True)
df_bwght.drop(df_bwght[df_bwght.fatheduc=='.'].index, inplace=True)

bwght = df_bwght['bwght']
cigs = df_bwght['cigs']
parity = df_bwght['parity']
faminc = df_bwght['faminc']
motheduc = df_bwght['motheduc']
fatheduc = df_bwght['fatheduc']
```

When I run `df_bwght.shape` it tells me that the necessary rows have been removed and the shape is now equal to `(1191,14)`. The shape for each individual column is also equal to `(1191,)`

Next I try to concatenate the variables of interest:

```
X = pd.Series(np.repeat(1,len(df_bwght)))
X = pd.concat([X,bwght],axis=1)
```

Both the variables being concatenated have the shapes `(1191,)`, but the resulting dataframe has the shape `(1357,2)`.

Can someone please help and explain to me why this happens?

Comment: This would be more suitable to ask on stackoverflow. https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you drop the rows from df_bwght, the indices were not dropped. They were probably like

```
> list(df_bwght.index)
[0,1,3,5,9,10,11,12,...]
```

When you join with the 1 vector (which has sequential indices), it skipped through the null indices.

You can do this to reset the indices

```
df_bwght.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

reference to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801806/pandas-concat-ignore-index-doesnt-work